# How working defer in concurrency code in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, defer-keyword

I have some code:

```
...
func Run(tasks []Task, n, m int) error {
    ...
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for t := range taskCh {
                if atomic.LoadInt32(&errCount) >= int32(m) {
                    return
                }

                if err := t(); err != nil {
                    atomic.AddInt32(&errCount, 1)
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    for _, t := range tasks {
        taskCh <- t
    }
    close(taskCh)
    wg.Wait()
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&errCount) >= int32(m) {
        err = ErrErrorsLimitExceeded
    }
    ...
}
```

and its work fine, but why its does not work when I writing operating close() wg.Wait and if... on the defer?

```
    ...
    defer func() {
        close(taskCh)
        wg.Wait()
        if atomic.LoadInt32(&errCount) >= int32(m) {
            err = ErrErrorsLimitExceeded
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    ...
```

when variable errCount = 0

Comment: Could you explain in more details what you expect vs what's happening ? For example : it's not clear whether your issue is a deadlock or something else.

Comment: there is no deadlock, just with the defer construction the variable errCount = 0, and not the specified number of errors. Although it should be incremented during the execution of the goroutine to read from the channel. 
arguments of Run function: n - count workers, m - maximum errors

Comment: Ok, please include this in your question : ".. works fine : the correct error count is reported". Do you have any code in the `...` at the end of your `Run(...)` function ?

Comment: @RamilKuvatov why you try to assign `err` inside `defer`? This shouldn't work unless you assign to named return args.

Comment: full code:
https://goplay.tools/snippet/AznRQ_7brG0 
its work. `err` not `nil`
but, when I write `defer { close(ch); wg.Wait(); if...}` code does not work. 
https://goplay.tools/snippet/TK4FzPwOIr1
why I don't can assign `err` inside defer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is golang limitation that you cannot change returned variables from defer functions. The correct way to do this is (pay attention to `(err error)` named return value):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func someFunction() (err error) {
    defer func() {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Some error")
    }()

    err = fmt.Errorf("Some other error")

    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(someFunction())
}
```

https://goplay.tools/snippet/9fwcqTIwhow